# Java bounded wildcards in C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, generics, bounded-wildcard

I'm stuck with this problem for several hours. I'm trying to find an equivalent method for C#.

**Java**, works:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<BaseList<? extends Base>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new DerivedList());
  }
}

public class BaseList<T extends Base>
{

}

public class Base
{

}

public class DerivedList extends BaseList<Derived>
{

}

public class Derived extends Base
{

}
```

I need an equivalent method for `ArrayList<BaseList<? extends Base>>` in C#. I hope someone help me.

And is it posible in C# to wildcard your variables??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that exactly as you describe, but there are workarounds. One is mentioned in another answer, another is to use interface instead:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<IBaseList<Base>>();
        list.Add(new DerivedList());
    }
}
// note "out" here
public interface IBaseList<out T> where T : Base {

}

public class BaseList<T> : IBaseList<T> where T : Base {

}

public class Base {

}

public class DerivedList : IBaseList<Derived> {

}

public class Derived : Base {

}
```

Comment: If I'm using this method I'm having the same problem as mentioned in the comments of Lucas Trzesniewski

Comment: You cannot declare "List<T> Entries" property in that interface, because it will violate variance (that "out" keyword). However, you can declare it as "IEnumeable<T> Entries" if that will suite your needs.

Answer (score 1):

C# uses runtime type reification, whereas Java uses type erasure. Which means that in Java, `ArrayList<Foo>` is the same class as `ArrayList<Bar>` at runtime. This is *not* the case in C#, so you can't just throw away the type parameter like that.

You can try to work around that like this:

```
public abstract class BaseList
{
}

public class BaseList<T> : BaseList
    where T : Base
{
}
```

Then use a `List<BaseList>`

Comment: Thank you! But do you know how can I access a property in `BaseList<T>` form an element in the `List<BaseList>`?

Comment: @boraida If it doesn't depend on `T`, move it to `BaseList` instead. You haven't provided the definition of your classes, so I can't say much more.

Comment: It actually depends on `T`. The property is `public virtual List<T> Entries { get; }`, made it virtual so the derived class can override it and add the `XmlElement` attribute to it. Any tips to achieve this?